# buffer problem when making serial communication with C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port, buffer

I am working on for serial communication using C++. I am calling linux command with C++. One port I am using works as transmitter and the other part is working as a receiver.

This is how transmitter works,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ofstream wfile;
char byte[40];
int n=0;

int main()
{
  while(true)
    {
      wfile.open("/dev/ttyUSB1");
      sprintf(byte,"message : %d\n",n);
      wfile << byte;
      wfile.close();
      printf("%s",byte);
      n++;
      sleep(1);
    }
}
```

And in the terminal window, I see result as

```
message : 0
message : 1
message : 2
message : 3
message : 4
message : 5
message : 6
message : 7
message : 8
message : 9
```

In the receiver part, my C++ script is written as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char var[100];
  FILE *fp;
  while(true)
    {
      fp=popen("cat /dev/ttyUSB0","r");
      fgets(var,sizeof(var),fp);
      printf("%s",var);
      pclose(fp);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I am expecting to get same result at the terminal window of my receiver's side.

I see a result something like

```
message : 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
... (repeats about 100 time)

 1
 1
 1
message : 2







...(void for about 100 line)



message : 3






...


message : 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
: 4
...
```

Something like this. I am assuming this is a problem with the buffer in the serial port. Moreover, Receiver is showing messages from old buffers which is not even initialized! Is there any way to fix this as I intended?

Comment: Assuming you've connected a cable from one port to the other...  Are both ports configured with the same baud rate, start/stop and parity bits?  I don't see any _true_ serial programming here.  You're just writing to a device and reading stream output from a process.  Read some documentation about how the Linux serial devices work in relation to reading data multiple times.  You might need smarter logic similar to how `tail -f` works.

Comment: Your sender is sleeping, but your receiver is not. The sender updates the file then sleeps for 1ms. During that 1ms, the receiver reads the value many times.

Comment: @dmedine `fgets` should block until data arrives, so no sleep required. 임성래 tweak the code to check all of the return codes. For all you know `wfile.open("/dev/ttyUSB1");` failed and nothing was ever written.

Comment: @user4581301, I don't think `fgets` will block here. It is called between an open and close of the file. IRC, if you do this on Linux it will read the file, new data or no. (But I've been wrong before ;-))

Comment: Why use `popen` and `cat` at all here?  Wouldn't it make more sense to open `/dev/ttyUSB0` _once_ in the receiver and read any incoming data direct?

Comment: With a file, yes. You'll keep reading the file over and over. With a virtual file like a serial port I'm under the impression that once read, the stuff's gone and not served up again. But I've never tried anything as abusive as what this program's doing. I'd expect the `fgets` to either return an (ignored) error pretty much instantly or block and wait for a newline or EOF, and there's pretty much no way to get an eof out of a serial port. Mind you, I just now noticed the use of `popen`, thanks @Paul , rather than `fopen`, and All bets are off.

Comment: Yeah, the `popen` wrecks everything. @dmedine 's dead right.

Comment: What should I use instead of popen then?

Comment: Open and close the file outside of the while loop. This will at least cause `fgets` to block. However, it won't help you establish when the sender starts writing, which it appears is something you need. You will also need a way to exit the loop. As paddy points out, this isn't actually doing any serial communication. You are simply reading and writing to a file. It just so happens to be the file that Linux uses for reading and writing data to that hardware device. Everything is a file in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to fix

**Check return value of `fgets()`**

Simplify as desired.

```
if (fgets(var,sizeof(var),fp)) {
  printf("<%s>\n",var);
} else {
  printf("Nothing this time.\n");
}
```

---

GTG